# Replace wrapping tags and reverse

Tags: c#, xslt, ckeditor, xslt-1.0

We have a legacy system that requires a format which is not html but is close enough to be confusing. On our shiny front end website we have an instance of CKEditor that allows users to edit this a-bit-like-html-but-not-really format.

The *big* difference is that our format does not understand `<p>` tags. It expects new lines to be formatted with `<br />` instead. CKEditor can be set to operate in `BR` mode but, perhaps unsurprisingly, this causes some annoying user interface bugs.

As an alternative, I'm considering allowing it to run in its default `P` mode and replacing the tags on the server with some XSLT. This is easy enough in the one direction:

Transforming:

```
<root>
<p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p>
<p><b>Test</b></p>
</root>
```

With:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Replace `[p]contents[/p]` with `contents[br /]` -->
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/><br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Results in:

```
<root>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/><b>Test</b><br/></root>
```

The question is, have I lost too much information to do the same process in reverse? And if not, what's the best way of approaching this? Is XSLT even the right option?

Comment: 1) Why does your output contain `Test` five times when it's there only four times in the input? Is that intentional? 2) You have lost the information where your `<p>` elements started. If there are no nested `<p>` elements in the input and you want to assume that everything is inside a `<p>` element, the transformation in the other direction should be feasible.

Comment: 1) Ooops, fixed. 2) I think it's safe to assume that there are no nested `p` tags and that there is no content that is not contained in a `p` tag.

Comment: I guess the question should really be, is XSLT the best tool to do this transformation in reverse?

Comment: My understanding of what you want to do is that you want to take the html that is output from CKEdit and transform it using xslt to replace <p>...</p>-paragraphs with <br/>. If that is your approach I think you are begging for trouble :) Html is often not so, in a xml sense, well formed. Loading incorrect xml into a xsl transformation throws an exception. I would choose another appoach. In fact I think you'd be better off and have less trouble just doing Regex.Replace

Comment: CKEditor outputs XHTML, so with a little manipulation I think I can guarantee valid XML. I think that XSLT is a reasonable tool for the transformation shown above, however I'm pretty convinced it will not work the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="k1"
  match="root/node()[not(self::br)]" 
  use="generate-id(following-sibling::br[1])"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="br" mode="wrap"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br" mode="wrap">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', generate-id())"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With Saxon 6.5.5 that converts

```
<root>Test<br/>Test<br/>Test<br/><b>Test</b><br/></root>
```

into

```
<root><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p><b>Test</b></p></root>
```

Comment: Very nice! I had just about conviced myself that it was impossible.